# Should I meet uniformity regarding using/avoiding contractions?

Tags: contractions

Which of the following is the most accepted rule regarding contractions (such as doesn't, isn't, ...) in academic formal papers?

- > Never use contractions.
- > If you use contractions once in a paper, do the same everywhere else in that paper.
- > Use/avoid contractions wherever you like.

Comment: Note that not all contractions are created equal. It's more informal to write "shouldn'tve" than it is to write "shouldn't have".

Comment: This is a writing style question - off topic here. Unless you adhere to some style guide, this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules accepted by whom? You need to consult a relevant style guide. Your academic institution should be able to provide you with guidance.

Individual institutions may well have their own rules, but they are likely to be very similar. For example, Birmingham City University (UK) has this to say about contractions in its [style guide](http://library.bcu.ac.uk/learner/writingguides/1.20.htm):

> - don't (do not!) use contractions (eg it's, he'll, it'd etc): always use the full form (it is/has, he will, it would/had).

Comment: Isn't there a general rule for academic papers or formal texts? Also, regarding your suggestion to avoid contractions, how come they are used so frequently in academic books and essays.

Comment: Why would there be a "general" rule? Who would set it? Anyway, answer edited.

Comment: Interesting to note that the style guide itself isn't written in what it defines as an academic writing style.

Comment: @sumelic Written by a Godel theorist, perhaps.